# TFS 2010 how to build on a server with windows server 2008 with VS 2012

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

I currently have a build box that is windows server 2008.
We are currently using TFS 2010 as our source control.

The project we have started is in Visual studio 2012.  When I try to automate the build I get a fair few erros

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\Builds\1\Test MVC 4 Application\Build Development - MVC 4 Test App\Sources\Project\TestMVC4\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.5.1,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{GAC}".
          Considered "System.Net.Http", which was not found in the GAC.
          For SearchPath "{RawFileName}".
          Considered treating "System.Net.Http" as a file name, but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "C:\Builds\1\Test MVC 4 Application\Build Development - MVC 4 Test App\Binaries\".
          Considered "C:\Builds\1\Test MVC 4 Application\Build Development - MVC 4 Test App\Binaries\System.Net.Http.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Builds\1\Test MVC 4 Application\Build Development - MVC 4 Test App\Binaries\System.Net.Http.exe", but it didn't exist.
  Primary reference "System.Net.Http.WebRequest".
```

I assume this is because I need to update the build server with visual studio 2012.  But when I try to install it, it says the server is out of date and does not support visual studio 2012... is there any options? or do I have to just update the server?  I am sure someone else would have come across this issue before

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last lines of your log, you see that MSBuild is looking for the assembly in your project. So you could add the missing DLL to your binaries folder and check it in into source control.